# Series object to stacked Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df

```
   a  b  c                     
1  0  2  1
2  0  2  2
3  0  3  2
4  1  1  7
```

First I tried to get all permutations of c within grupby of a and b

```
s=pd.Series({x: list(it.permutations(y) )for x , y in  df.groupby(['a','b']).c})
s.to_frame()

      0                     
0  2  [(1,2),(2,1)]
   3  [(2,)]   
1  1  [(7,)]
```

I basically want to stack the df, but since there is for example two possible tuples in row 1, I want all possible combinations within groups of 'a':

```
   a  b  c                    
1  0  2  1
   0  2  2
   0  3  2  
2  0  2  2
   0  2  1
   0  3  2 
3  1  1  7
```

since I need all combinations, explode() is not working as I want.

Answer (score 0):

Keep `s` as pd.series and run explode twice,

```
df = s.explode().explode().rename_axis(['a', 'b']).reset_index(name='c')
```

output

```
    a   b   c
0   0   2   1
1   0   2   2
2   0   2   2
3   0   2   1
4   0   3   2
5   1   1   7
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. the explode twice only works if there is these two tuples, but it can have multiple different  Your output is also sligthly different, since there is one row missing